# Copy Previous Cell data into textbox

Tags: excel, vba, database, userform

Just looking to create a code that would enable me to have a user form textbox pull data from previous cell (As it's a data entry register) and when the cell data is found want it to display within the worksheet to get it to follow a sequence which exists within the worksheet.

Summary: when Column A "TCNumber" previous cell value = "TC00010" Then show value in TXBTCNumber (Textbox for TC Number values) AND add 1 to found data and add new value into newrow cell.

P.S. If possible can I get it to find the entire value (Example: TC00010) NOT just the numbers

Found a code that finds the previous cell data and adds it into the textbox already expect it only show the last two digits of the TC Number instead of the entire value

Current Code:

```
With UserForm1.TXBTCNumber

Dim TCNum As Integer
Dim TC As String
Dim rows As String
Dim value As String
Dim concat As String
Set ws = Worksheets("Material Tracibility Register")


rows = ws.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

Dim a As String
'Column
a = "A"
concat = a & rows
'Value in last low is below
TC = Range(concat).value
TCNum = Mid(TC, 3, 6) + 1

UserForm1.TXBTCNumber.value = TCNum
End With
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to copy only the last 2 caracters you will need simply to add substring function to your code which helps to cut the string TCNum and copy the part which you need.

**Example :**

```
With UserForm1.TXBTCNumber

Dim TCNum As Integer
Dim TC As String
Dim rows As String
Dim value As String
Dim concat As String
Set ws = Worksheets("Material Tracibility Register")


rows = ws.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

Dim a As String
'Column
a = "A"
concat = a & rows
'Value in last low is below
TC = Range(concat).value
TCNum = Mid(TC, 3, 6) + 1

UserForm1.TXBTCNumber.value = TCNum.Substring(TCNum.Length - 2)

End With
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks Anas, But I think you misunderstood the code you supplied is doing exactly what i didn't want :( I wanted a code which could identify the value of the previous cell and add a value of 1 to the value found, then once it has found and added one to the value of the previous cell i wanted it to display the new value in the user form textbox to show the user the next number in the sequence.

Comment: Example Case: If cell "A10" Has a value of "TC000008" Then the user form would see that and add +1 Making the new value "TC000009" And then display this new value into the userform textbox and when the user clicks input the form will load the new value ("TC000009") Into the next row within the worksheet.